# Django reset password sender and receiver inverted

Tags: python, django, django-email

In Django my project I add the "Frorget password" link.

In my urls.py:

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my settings.py:

```
# Email setting
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_FROM = 'account@test.io'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'YUIJKHKBKBD7879'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'By6786ghgkgk//89jkjlnCkVt'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

but when I go to my page /accounts/password_reset/ and insert the email for what I whant to change the password es. mario.rossi@gmail.com, when I click The Submit button, system return:

> SMTPDataError at /accounts/password_reset/
>   (554, b'Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: mario.rossi@gmail.com, webmaster@localhost')

But mario.rossi@gmail.com is not the sender, it's the receiver! Why django reset password does seem to use `EMAIL_FROM` from settings.py for send email From?

Comment: This one will help you https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses/issues/16

Comment: Are you running this on your local machine or a remote machine?

Comment: I run on a ec2 remote instance, but if i try using boto3 ses from shell all was done